# ActiveRecord Model treating database view's field as integer instead of boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a database view that I've linked to a ActiveRecord Model. When I call the model `AdherenceActivity.all` it returns

```
[
    [0] #<AdherenceActivity:0x007fec986b5328> {
        :adherence_date => Wed, 01 Nov 2017,
            :patient_id => 10000,
               :morning => 0.0,
             :afternoon => 1.0,
               :evening => 1.0,
                 :night => nil
    }
]
```

It's not interpreting `1` or `0` as `true` or `false`. How can I update the model to return a boolean instead of `1.0` or `0.0` ?

**EDIT**

For clarification, this is a database view, not a table. Here is my migration for the DB View (Oracle SQL)

```
class CreateAdherenceActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE VIEW adherence_activities AS
        SELECT
          adherence_date,
          patient_id,
          sum(case when scheduled_time = 'morning'   then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as morning,
          sum(case when scheduled_time = 'afternoon' then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as afternoon,
          sum(case when scheduled_time = 'evening'   then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as evening,
          sum(case when scheduled_time = 'night'     then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as night
        FROM medication_adherences
        GROUP BY adherence_date, patient_id
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP VIEW adherence_activities"
  end
end
```

Rails 5.1, Ruby 2.4.1

Comment: Can you change the view? `sum` usually produces a `numeric` type, hence the `1.0` and `0.0` values. Does the Oracle adapter use some sort of small integer for booleans (like MySQL does) or is there a native boolean type in Oracle? Basically, you have to replace the `sum` with something that produces a boolean (if that type is available) or add a type cast.

Comment: @muistooshort Unfortunately not. Oracle doesn't support a Boolean datatype. It only represents them as 1 or 0. ActiveRecord interprets this as true/false when you've specified the datatype in your migration. Since this is a view I'm unable to tell AR that it's a boolean (or rather, that's my question, how can I make AR interpret this field as a boolean)

Comment: How are you interacting with the view? Could you simply override the `morning`, `afternoon`, ... methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no responses to this, I will give my 2cents.  I think the way I would go about this is adding definitions to the type Classes themselves and then use getters/setters like so..

```
class AdherenceActivity < ApplicationRecord

  def morning
    #do nothing if nil
    return if @morning.nil?
    #convert to boolean
    @morning.to_bool
  end

  def morning=(val)
    super(val.to_f)
  end
  #And repeat for other boolean values...

end

class FalseClass; def to_f; 0.0 end end
class TrueClass; def to_f; 1.0 end end
class Float; def to_bool; not self.zero? end end 
#NOTE: I am unsure what data type the DB/Rails is setting the 1s and 0s to
#But it looks like a float
```

'true' and 'false' have their own separate classes in Ruby.  What this is doing is adding a new method (to_f) to the end of each class that simply returns a 0.0 in the event of a 'false' class, and a 1.0 in the event of a 'true' class.

For a more visual explanation,
*In irb:*

---

```
irb(main):001:0> false.class
=> FalseClass
irb(main):002:0> true.class
=> TrueClass
```

---

```
irb(main):008:0> false.to_f
=> 0.0
irb(main):009:0> true.to_f
=> 1.0
```

---

Then as far as the conversion from float back to boolean goes, add on a class to Float that will check whether it's zero or not.
( 0.zero? == true so need the opposite of that, eg. not 0.zero? )

**Extra Credit:** 
I recommend adding the methods as stated because when you start getting into more complex cases, it keeps things DRY, short, and sweet.
*Suppose you had a lot of different boolean values to convert.*

```
class AdherenceActivity < ApplicationRecord
  #Your list of boolean/float columns
  %w[morning afternoon evening night].each do |s|
    #Getter methods
    define_method(s) do
      #do nothing if nil value received
      return if self.instance_variable_get("@#{s}").nil?
      #Get the instance variable with name, eg. @night
      self.instance_variable_get("@#{s}").to_bool
    end
    #Setter methods
    define_method("#{s}=") do |val|
      super(val.to_f)
    end
  end

end

class FalseClass; def to_f; 0.0 end end
class TrueClass; def to_f; 1.0 end end
class Float; def to_bool; not self.zero? end end
#Assuming float data type
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This is the route I ended up going earlier today. I'll give you the point since we both came to this conclusion. Extra credit way is clever, but I defined each morning/afternoon/evening/night methods explicitly to make it clear. FWIW I don't need setter methods since this is a DB View and values can't be changed

Comment: This also needs to handle `nil` values and leave return `nil` instead of `false`. I did `def morning; return if super.nil?; super == 1`

Comment: @theartofbeing Yeah I forgot about nil.  Another way to do this would be to just add rescue nil (updated ans.) as you know the db values will be 1, 0, nil.  The If/then is much more explicit though, I suppose.  Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Though inline `rescue nil` sometimes seems elegant, it is bad practice. Google "ruby rescue nil" :)

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as what @brad-axe posted, but handles the `nil` case. I would have liked to solve this on the ActiveRecord/Query level, as this doesn't change the return values of the query, but changes the value that is returned when I call morning/afternoon/evening/night on the object.

I'm selecting @brad-axe because it's the right thing to do, but wanted to post my solution for clarity.

```
  def morning
    return if super.nil?
    super == 1
  end

  def afternoon
    return if super.nil?
    super == 1
  end

  def evening
    return if super.nil?
    super == 1
  end

  def night
    return if super.nil?
    super == 1
  end
```